# Convert DateTime to Swatch Internet Time (Beat time)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-conversion

I was searching to convert DateTime to Swatch internet time in C#. I did not find anything. How do i convert DateTime to beats?

EDIT:
Found the solution, will post it as answer soon:

```
var time = DateTime.Now;  //get the current time
var utc1 = time.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(1); //convert the given DateTime to universal time and add one hour (internet time is based on UTC+1)
var beats = utc1.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds / 86400d; //get the milliseconds of the given day and divide it to the number of seconds of a day
```

In one line:

```
var beats = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(1).TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds / 86400d
```

As DateTime-extensions:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static double ToInternetTimeDouble(this DateTime time)
    {
        return time.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(1).TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds / 86400d;
    }

    public static int ToInternetTimeInt(this DateTime time)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(time.ToInternetTimeDouble()));
    }

    public static string ToInternetTimeStr(this DateTime time)
    {
        return time.ToInternetTimeStr(false);
    }

    public static string ToInternetTimeStr(this DateTime time, bool decimals)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "@{0}", decimals ? string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.00}", time.ToInternetTimeDouble()) : time.ToInternetTimeInt().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some question there? If not, this post doesn't belong here, this site is not for sharing code.

Comment: You can use both. With you TotalSeconds you have to write TotalSeconds / 86.4d

Comment: If you really post this solution here at SO, you maybe create in the first step a real question (e.g. how to convert from datetime to swatch beat?) and immediately answer your own question with this solution. Otherwise risks are high that this will be closed, cause it simply isn't a question.

Comment: Hi svick, I had the question how to convert this and solved it by myself. I think there are a lot of people who have to convert this and are happy to get the code without finding it by themelves. Should i better post an answer with the code and leave the question in the first post?

Comment: I cannot answer within 8 hours... will add it in 8 hours.

Comment: Start from Utc+1 just because Swatch HQ is located in this zone? So SILLY.